# How to prevent Firefox from bringing all of its windows to the foreground when clicking only one window?

Tags: 22.04, firefox, focus

Ubuntu 22.04.
Firefox 122.0.1

I am observing the following behavior.

If I have multiple Firefox windows and I click on one of them, all the Firefox windows that are not minimized are brought to the foreground.

I would like to avoid this behavior and have only the window that I click on to come to the foreground.

How to do that?

Comment: I am not seeing that behavior - I have the same version of Ubuntu and FF. 
Is this new behavior or is it preexisting? If now, have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Does this happen when you are using more than 3 windows? I am using the same operating system and browser version and have not observed this behavior. I suspect there is a chance that your mouse is double-clicking and when you click on a window, the one behind it is also minimized by double-clicking.

It might be interesting to misalign the windows and test to confirm if it's a double-click problem.

Answer (score 1):

All solved.

This behavior was caused by the setting "Rise together" of the "Tiling Assitant" Gnome extension.[image]

Comment: always a good idea when encountering unusual behaviour to start by disabling extensions one by one until the issue is found.